# LibGDX anyone switched to lwjgl3? Can't draw sprites

Tags: java, libgdx

After switching to lwjgl3 in LibGDX spritebatches no longer draw... Anyone had any success with this?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @m.antkowicz Windows 8, I just switch off lwjgl3 in my desktop launcher and bam my sprites all draw. Keep in mind I am using libGDX implementation of lwjgl3 so I am not going directly to lwjgl3.

Comment: Probably you are using libGDX'es version that do not supports lwjgl3 yet - it is still under construction [take a look](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3673) - you can use gitHub version though

Comment: @m.antkowicz I followed the exact instructions on that link and batch sprites are not drawing... have you been able to get it working?

Comment: I haven't tried yet - I'm interested why do you need this? Is there any necessity or just because? If just because I would not migrate to lwjgl3 before deploying official support

Comment: @m.antkowicz the lwjgl3 controller support is something I am interested in due to the additional features.